# Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger Version Incompatibility

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Community on my local machine. On another machine, I am running the Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger, found [HERE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48155). I do not understand why, when I run the Attach To Process and enter the IP of my remote machine, it gives me the error in the image below. There is no other more up to date version that I am aware of.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the "Details" on the page you linked to you will see the following (emphasis mine):

> The Remote Tools are intended for computers that don't have Visual Studio so that you can debug, test, and profile apps that are executing on them. Visual Studio must be installed on the development computer that's connected to, or uses the data collected from, the remote computer. **Connecting to the remote debugger and profiler that are included in the Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015 is supported in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015**.

You're using Visual Studio Community, not Visual Studio Enterprise. The error message could certainly be more clear, but the answer is right there on the download page.

**Update**

You might also want to check out this page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx). On it it states:

> You must install the version of the remote tools that matches the version of your Visual Studio installation. Mismatched versions are not recommended.
>
> In addition, you must install the remote tools that have the same architecture as the operating system on which you want to install it. In other words, if you want to debug a 32-bit application on a a remote computer running a 64-bit operating system, you must install the 64-bit version of the remote tools on the remote computer.

There are links to [Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-remote-tools) and [Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49986&44F86079-8679-400C-BFF2-9CA5F2BCBDFC=1).

Comment: So your interpretation of that is that remote debugging is not supported by Visual Studio Community edition?

Comment: This is very strange, as I had successfully connected to this same computer a month or two ago. The problem is that so much has happened since then, I'm super fuzzy on all the details for it, so it's frustrating when something worked before and now it doesn't

Comment: To help clarify, remote debugging is a basic scenario that is *definitely* supported with all editions of visual studio. The issue is a version mismatch between the remote tools and visual studio.